# Curl command - output is different

Tags: curl, user-interface

when I run this command in the UI its returning 32 ids:

http://csc2cxn00001736.cloud.kp.org:6080/api/v1/application/exchange/pickup?offset=0&orderBy=name

while when I run this curl command in the server its returning only 10 ids:

```
curl -k -sS -X GET -u "admin:Secret2cQA"
"http://csc2cxn00001736.cloud.kp.org:6080/api/v1/application/exchange/pickup?offset=0&orderBy=name" 
-H "accept: application/json" | jq '.results[]."@id"'
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. The site is all about questions and answers. Your post is a story, not a question. Please [edit] and formulate a question. I suspect it may be "why?" or "how can I make the latter work like the former?". Note these are different questions; don't let us guess what your question is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.